Hibernate slow performance on execute query
I have Hibenrate v.5.6.15 and SpringBoot v.2.7.18
I have this entites:
public class Race {
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "race", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Car> cars;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "race", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<UpdateStatus> statusUpdates;
}

public class Car {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "RACE_ID")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Race race;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "OWNER_ID")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Owner owner;
}


public class UpdateStatus {
        
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "RACE_ID")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Race race;
}

Now I'm trying to execute a query where i need everything for a race, like cars, updateStatus and cars owner.
If i try to do EAGER or left join fetch in query i got MultipleBagFetchException, so i tried to make a two queries, one to fetch Race with Cars and Owners, and one to fetch UpdateStatus.
List<Race> notUpdated = entityManager.createQuery(
                "select distinct r from Race r "
                        + "left join fetch r.cars c "
                        + "left join fetch c.owner "
                        + "where r.status = '0'  ", Race.class)
            .setHint(QueryHints.PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false)
            .getResultList();

notUpdated = entityManager.createQuery(
                "select distinct r from Race r "
                        + "left join fetch  r.statusUpdates "
                        + "where r in :notUpdated ", Race.class)
            .setParameter("notUpdated", notUpdated)
            .setHint(QueryHints.PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false)
            .getResultList();

But the problem is that the first query (one to fetch Race with Cars and Owners) is very slow compared to execution time in DBeaver (I'm using DB2 database)
In DBeaver it's like 30-50ms but in Spring its up to 5-6 seconds
What are possible reasons for this behavior?
